# Can’t gracefully shut down a node + Express app (node http server's close function does not complete)

Tags: node.js, express

I want the Express.js-based server of the app I am working on to properly close all connections before exiting the node process when a shutdown signal (SIGTERM or SIGINT) is sent.

I have slightly modified the `express-graceful-shutdown` middleware ([which is really simple](https://github.com/serby/express-graceful-shutdown/blob/master/index.js)), so the relevant part of my code looks approximately as follows:

**server.js**

```
import gracefulShutdown from './tools/graceful-shutdown';

const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running`);
});

app.use(gracefulShutdown(server));
```

**graceful-shutdown.js:**

```
function gracefulShutdownMiddleware(server) {

  let shuttingDown = false;
  const forceTimeout = 10 * 1000; // giving the app 10 seconds to shutdown gracefully


  process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulExit); // listen for TERM signal (e.g. kill)
  process.on ('SIGINT', gracefulExit); // listen for INT signal (e.g. Ctrl-C)

  function gracefulExit() {

    if (shuttingDown) return;
    shuttingDown = true;
    console.log('Received kill signal (SIGTERM), shutting down');

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down');
      process.exit(1);
    }, forceTimeout);

    server.close(function () {
      console.log('Closed out remaining connections.');
      process.exit();
    });

  }

  function middleware(req, res, next) {
    if (!shuttingDown) return next()
    res.set('Connection', 'close')
    res.status(503).send('Server is in the process of restarting.')
  }

  return middleware

}

export default gracefulShutdownMiddleware;
```

The problem I am observing is this. If I shut down the node server immediately after it starts, it shuts down as expected (function `gracefulExit` in the middleware works correctly, `server.close` executes fine, and the callback to `server.close` prints out the console message). If, however, I open the browser and actually visit my app on the localhost, so that the server has some work to do, and then try to shut the server down, the server.close function does not seem to finish (so it never calls the callback with `process.exit` until finally the setTimeout calls its own callback and forcefully shuts down the app.

The server.close function is [this function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/68ba9aa0fb6693a1fb5dd114a3ddbe447517c0dd/lib/net.js#L1487) from node’s lib.

Could you help me figure out why node server’s `close` function may fail to complete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Shut Down My Express Server Gracefully When Its Process Is Killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003870/how-do-i-shut-down-my-express-server-gracefully-when-its-process-is-killed)

Comment: You are experiencing the same issue as in the question above. Feel free to also [check out my answer there as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291800/1056679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.close()` doesn't actually close any active connections, it will only stop *new* connections from being made, and it'll wait for the active connections to get closed (by the client).

If clients are connected that keep a connection open (say using a keep-alive connection), the callback may never get called.

There's a package called [`http-shutdown`](https://github.com/thedillonb/http-shutdown) that will help with gracefully shutting down an HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you! I read through the code of `http-shutdown`, and its approach seems to be working fine. I am still slightly confused with what [this piece of their code](https://github.com/thedillonb/http-shutdown/blob/master/index.js#L29) is doing though.

Comment: @azangru from the looks of it, the module tracks all incoming connections (enabling it to close them when called to shutdown), and the code you're referring to basically cleans up connections that finished (so it won't get closed again when shutting down, because the connection was already finished).