# How do I shut down my Express server gracefully when its process is killed?

Tags: node.js, express

When running my Express application in production, I want to shut down the server gracefully when its process is killed (i.e. a `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` is sent).

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ ping: true }));

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running…'));

setInterval(() => server.getConnections(
    (err, connections) => console.log(`${connections} connections currently open`)
), 1000);

process.on('SIGTERM', shutDown);
process.on('SIGINT', shutDown);

function shutDown() {
    console.log('Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully');
    server.close(() => {
        console.log('Closed out remaining connections');
        process.exit(0);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.error('Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down');
        process.exit(1);
    }, 10000);
}
```

When I run it and call the URL http://localhost:3000/ in a browser, the log statement in the setInterval function will keep printing “1 connection currently open” until I actually close the browser window. Even closing the tab will keep the connection open, apparently.

So when I kill my server by hitting Ctrl+C, it will run into the timeout and print “Could not close connections” after 10 seconds, all the while continuing to print “1 connection open”.

Only if I close the browser window before killing the process I get the “closed out remaining connections” message.

**What am I missing here? What is the proper way to shut down an Express server gracefully?**

Comment: Can you define "gracefully"?

Comment: What is it that you think you need to do gracefully?  The OS will close your server, close all sockets, free all memory, etc... when the process is killed.  So, we're wondering what else you think you need to do to make a "graceful" exit?

Comment: I assumed that if I didn't call server.close, browsers that are in the middle of a request (they usually take around 100-200 ms) would get an error. What else is server.close for?

Comment: Did you read [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback)?

Comment: I have read it now  so close just stops the server from accepting new connections, but it does not actively close connections that browsers are keeping alive.

Comment: @PatrickHund has a really important point here (driven by robertklep). I'm sure this is what has been driving me nutzo for a few hours.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I added a listener for connections opening on the server, storing references to those connections in an array. When the connections are closed, they are removed from the array.

When the server is killed, each of the connection is closed by calling its `end` methods. For some browsers (e.g. Chrome), this is not enough, so after a timeout, I call `destroy` on each connection.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ ping: true }));

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running…'));

setInterval(() => server.getConnections(
    (err, connections) => console.log(`${connections} connections currently open`)
), 1000);

process.on('SIGTERM', shutDown);
process.on('SIGINT', shutDown);

let connections = [];

server.on('connection', connection => {
    connections.push(connection);
    connection.on('close', () => connections = connections.filter(curr => curr !== connection));
});

function shutDown() {
    console.log('Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully');
    server.close(() => {
        console.log('Closed out remaining connections');
        process.exit(0);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.error('Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down');
        process.exit(1);
    }, 10000);

    connections.forEach(curr => curr.end());
    setTimeout(() => connections.forEach(curr => curr.destroy()), 5000);
}
```

Comment: Is calling `.end()` on a socket that's still active different from what Node (or the OS) does when the process terminates?

Answer (score 26):

The problem you are experiencing is that all modern browsers reuse single connection for multiple requests. This is called **keep-alive connections**.

The proper way to handle this is to monitor all new connections and requests and to track status of each connection (is it idle or active right now). Then you can forcefully close all idle connections and make sure to close active connections after current request is being processed.

I've implemented the [@moebius/http-graceful-shutdown](https://github.com/moebius-mlm/http-graceful-shutdown) module specifically designed to gracefully shutdown Express applications and Node servers overall. Sadly nor Express, nor Node itself doesn't have this functionality built-in.

Here's how it can be used with any Express application:

```js
const express = require('express');
const GracefulShutdownManager = require('@moebius/http-graceful-shutdown').GracefulShutdownManager;


const app = express();

const server = app.listen(8080);

const shutdownManager = new GracefulShutdownManager(server);

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  shutdownManager.terminate(() => {
    console.log('Server is gracefully terminated');
  });
});
```

Feel free to check-out [the module](https://github.com/moebius-mlm/http-graceful-shutdown), the GitHub page has more details.

Comment: Can you please explain how is this different than what happens when the OS kills the node process?

Comment: @Purefan from the module's documentation: `When your application's process is interrupted by the operating system (by passing SIGINT or SIGTERM signals) by default the server is terminated right away and all open connections are brutally severed. This means that if some client was in the process of sending or receiving data from your server it will encounter an error. This could easily lead to escalating errors down the chain and data corruption.`

Answer (score 12):

There is open source project https://github.com/godaddy/terminus recommended by the creators of Express (https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/healthcheck-graceful-shutdown.html).

The basic example of terminus usage:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const terminus = require('@godaddy/terminus');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

function onSignal() {
  console.log('server is starting cleanup');
  // start cleanup of resource, like databases or file descriptors
}

async function onHealthCheck() {
  // checks if the system is healthy, like the db connection is live
  // resolves, if health, rejects if not
}

terminus(server, {
  signal: 'SIGINT',
   healthChecks: {
    '/healthcheck': onHealthCheck,
  },
  onSignal
});

server.listen(3000);
```

terminus has a lot of options in case you need server lifecycle callbacks (ie. to deregister instance from service registry, etc.):

```
const options = {
  // healtcheck options
  healthChecks: {
    '/healthcheck': healthCheck    // a promise returning function indicating service health
  },

  // cleanup options
  timeout: 1000,                   // [optional = 1000] number of milliseconds before forcefull exiting
  signal,                          // [optional = 'SIGTERM'] what signal to listen for relative to shutdown
  signals,                          // [optional = []] array of signals to listen for relative to shutdown
  beforeShutdown,                  // [optional] called before the HTTP server starts its shutdown
  onSignal,                        // [optional] cleanup function, returning a promise (used to be onSigterm)
  onShutdown,                      // [optional] called right before exiting

  // both
  logger                           // [optional] logger function to be called with errors
};
```

Comment: hi @Przmek Nowak can you help me with how to health check node server.

Comment: Only works on Windows: https://github.com/godaddy/terminus/issues/71

Comment: I've using it on kubernetes and there was ok

Comment: note bind command was changed from `terminus ` to `createTerminus`

Comment: "recommended by the creators of Express" is a bit of an overstatement. They even state: "Warning: This information refers to third-party sites, products, or modules that are not maintained by the Expressjs team. Listing here does not constitute an endorsement or recommendation from the Expressjs project team."

Answer (score 1):

If you allow me, there is even a better solution that involves less work by using `server-destroy` package. Internally this package will terminate gracefully each connection and then allow the server to be "destroyed". In this case we ensure to definitively end the express application (and potentially start it again if we use a call function). This works for me using electron, and can potentially be ported to a standard server:

```
const express = require('express')
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
const enableDestroy = require('server-destroy')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

export const wsServer = () => {
  try {
    let app = null
    let server = null

    const startServer = () => {
      if (app) {
        app = null
      }

      app = express()
      app.use(express.static('public'))
      app.use('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('hello!')
      })

      server = app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('websocket server is ready.')
        console.log(`Running webserver on http://localhost:${port}`)
      })

      enableDestroy(server)
    }

    const stopServer = () => {
      if (server !== null) {
        server.destroy()
        app = null
        server = null
      }
    }
    const restartServer = () => {
      stopServer()
      startServer()
    }

    ipcMain.on('start-socket-service', (event) => {
      startServer()
      console.log('Start Server...')
      event.returnValue = 'Service Started'
    })

    ipcMain.on('stop-socket-service', (event) => {
      stopServer()
      console.log('Stop Server...')
      event.returnValue = 'Service Stopped'
    })

    ipcMain.on('restart-socket-service', () => {
      restartServer()
    })

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/ladjs/graceful#express

```js
const express = require('express');
const Graceful = require('@ladjs/graceful');

const app = express();
const server = app.listen();
const graceful = new Graceful({ servers: [server] });
graceful.listen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Http terminator seems to be the 2022 solution that handles keep alive conections properly and force shutdown after some time
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-terminator

The main benefit of http-terminator is that:

- it does not monkey-patch Node.js API
- it immediately destroys all sockets without an attached HTTP request
- it allows graceful timeout to sockets with ongoing HTTP requests
- it properly handles HTTPS connections
- it informs connections using keep-alive that server is shutting down by setting a connection: close header
- it does not terminate the Node.js process

Answer (score -1):

Try the NPM [express-graceful-shutdown module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graceful-shutdown), Graceful shutdown will allow any connections including to your DB to finish, not allow any fresh/new ones to be established. Since you are working with express that may be the module you are looking for, however a quick NPM search will reveal a whole list of modules suited to Http servers etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried the graceful shutdown module, if you look at its code, you see that it does pretty much the same as my code: listen for SIGTERM, execute server.close when it happens. And when I change my code to use that middleware, the exact same thing happens: after the timeout period has elapsed, it does a process.exit(1) with a message “Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down”

Comment: Downvoted on principle. You linked an NPM module containing 40 lines of code. A 3rd party solution is completely unnecessary to solve this properly.

Comment: @PatrickHund What is strange, is that your answer has later date than this comment here, or the above answer.