# Multiple server instance attempts while running jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, supertest

Okay, So I've been writing tests for my node.js app using jest and supertest, for every test suite after the first, I'm getting an error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`, I believe this is because it attempts to start the server on every test file (I have multiple test files `*.test.js` in `/tests`)

The top part before tests are described in each test file looks something like this

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../index.js"); // the express server

jest.setTimeout(30000);

let token;

beforeAll(done => {
  request(app)
    .post("/api/users/login")
    .send({
      email: "email here",
      password: "password here"
    })
    .end((err, response) => {
      token = response.body.data; // save the token!
      done();
    });
});

afterAll(done => {
  //logout() //Not implemented yet
  done();
});

/* Test starts here */
```

So, I need to know how to prevent jest from attempting to initialize multiple instances of my server? is it possible to say have all this code run in a pre-test file or so? is there something I can add to my `afterAll` to cause it to stop the server so when another test starts it i'm good? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, so while removing the connection at each start and using concurrently per @Omar Sherif's answer was a valid workaround I found it unnecessarily complicated, setting up a globalSetup per jest's documentation was also a rather unnecessary hassle.

A simple solution I found was the following; since running jest sets the `NODE_ENV` to test, in my index.js folder, instead of just having my server listen to a network port which was unnecessary, I added a very simple if condition.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Running on ${port}`));
}
```

This seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is here

```js
const app = require("../index.js"); // the express server
```

Everytime you try to require the `index.js` you technically copy paste all the code from inside `index.js` to your test script.

Since you run multiple test files at the same time, each test attempts to run the same code inside `index.js`

You can read more on this http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: Thank you, I was aware that this is the error, so I had 2 possible solutions in mind, either terminating whatever ran from index.js after each test in `afterAll` or having a seperate file that runs pre-testing to have the server only run once, any idea how I could go either way?

Comment: I think you need to separate the core server from your tests, you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

The 1st arg you give to concurrently is `npm run start` to run your server and the 2nd arg is `npm run test` for example to run all your tests ...

It would look like this `"concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run test1\" \"npm run test2\" "`

Answer (score 1):

You can also have jest run tests synchronously to avoid the server being opened twice. Adjust your jest script in the `package.json` to add `--runInBand`. This way

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --watchAll --runInBand"
},
```

This worked for me!