# Active Handles created but not destroy even in Simple NODE JS App

Tags: node.js

I am using Node 10.10.0 latest version and below is the small peice of code that I am trying to execute.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();


async function fun1(req, resp){
    let response = await request.get('http://google.com');
      if (response.err) { console.log('error');}
      else { resp.send('fetched response'); };
  }

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fun1(req, res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I am also using **clinic doctor** to [check performance bottleneck for above code](https://github.com/nearform/node-clinic).

I am running command as below;

```
clinic doctor --on-port 'autocannon -c100 localhost:3000' -- node index.js
```

I get below console output on executing above command.

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
Running 10s test @ http://localhost:3000
100 connections

Stat         Avg    Stdev   Max
Latency (ms) 94.72  75.87   1077.87
Req/Sec      827    257.35  1248
Bytes/Sec    180 kB 55.7 kB 270 kB

9k requests in 11s, 1.96 MB read
9 errors (0 timeouts)
Analysing data
Generated HTML file is 3884.clinic-doctor.html
You can use this command to upload it:
clinic upload 3884.clinic-doctor
```

and also I get a nice UI generated and it opens automatically as below,

[image]

**QUESTION**
Why is my application when tested for performance bottleneck goes on creating Active Handles as seen in the 4th chart in the image? DO I need to close anything? Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, thanks a lot for this example I was seeking for a Node.js stress testing tool.

Your example is a not properly set, `request` does not work with Promises. There are [additional packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) out there that work with Bluebird or native promises.

I have tweaked your example using `async / await`:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const app = express();


function fun1(req, resp) {
  return request.get('http://google.com');
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await fun1();
    res.send('fetched response');
  } catch (error) {
    res.send('error')
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Results:

[image: node-clinic]

Keep in mind that you also have to gracefully shut down any hanging server instances as can be seen in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003870/how-do-i-shut-down-my-express-server-gracefully-when-its-process-is-killed).

Comment: Your code did not entertain autocannon load request. It ended up with errors. Can ou post your console output when you ran above code?

Comment: @AnkurSoni I have used the exact same command you have provided.

Comment: Yeah, but did you see the console? It landed up with errors timing out the requests. Kindly check.

Comment: You shall install `request` as well. `npm i --save request`